# Draw a Bitmap in Arc center?

Tags: android, android-canvas

In my Custom View, I draw multiple filled `Arc`s like this:

```
canvas.drawArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, sectorPaint);
```

Now, I want to draw an icon on the center of the Arc. I started with this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_icon);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, pointX, pointY, null); //pointX & pointY ??
```

However, I don't know what should I set for `pointX` and `pointY`. Here is the data I have:

- Oval center coordinates and radius.
- startAngle and sweepAngle (and therefore, endAngle can be derived)

Is there a way to know the values `pointX` and `pointY` giving those inputs?

---

Edit: an illustration sketch:

[image]

Comment: can you put a screen shot also of what you want to achieve

Comment: @SunnyKumarAditya Edited with a sketch. Take a look please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280941/543711) helped me a lot after some adjustments:

```
double radius = width/2;
double x = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(-angle);
double y = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(-angle);
```

Comment: I think that this only works if your start angle is 0. Is there a way to set a non-zero start and end angle and still get their center?

Answer (score 0):

Using your vars.

Try this:

```
double x = C.x + r * Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 180);
double y = C.y + r * Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 180);
```

where `theta` is end angle of `arc` - `start angle of arc`