# Find tanget Point in Circle

Tags: java, math

Giving this sketch:

[image]

Is it possible to find any tangent point (The blue ones) giving that you know:

- The center point of the circle (width/2, width/2).
- the *degree angle* of the line connecting the unknown point to the center (the angle is calculated from `start angle` point in CW direction).

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, it's definitely possible.

The radius is `width/2`.

You know the angle, so do the trigonometry.

Here is some code:

```
double radius = width/2;
double x = (radius)*Math.cos(-angle); // angle is in radians
double y = (radius)*Math.sin(-angle);
```

If the angle is in degrees, you can change it to radians like this.

`angle = angle/180.0*Math.PI;`

---

**EDIT**

Since you only want positive values, you can do this with your already-calculated `x` and `y`.

`x += radius;`

`y = radius - y;`

A video on the unit circle: http://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/v/unit-circle-definition-of-trig-functions

Comment: Yup. If the angle is 3 pi/2, for example, you'll get -1 for a `Math.sin(angle);`

Comment: But my drawing space accepts positive values. My canvas (The square area) is where I will draw the points.

Comment: What happened? Were you able to see the point? Do you have a screenshot of it. I must have messed up my arithmetic.

Comment: @iturki GOT IT. The angle is clockwise instead of counterclockwise. My bad. Try it now. I negated the angle in the first part.

Comment: I managed to solve it by adding the radius to both points. Thanks.

Comment: An easier way to convert degrees (e.g. 90) to radians is to use `Math.toRadians(degrees)`.

Comment: Also, I don't see where we set the STARTING degrees in your code example. I think it assumes that the arc starts from 0 degrees, where in fact, it may be something like - start: 20 degrees, end: 130 degrees. How should we calculate the center coordinates in this case?

Comment: @ColorWP.com His `start angle` is written in purple - it's the 0 degrees angle [as he states in the question]. Center coordinates? This question is just about finding the tangent point on a circle. The center coordinates are (width/2, width/2), as stated in the question. I guess I don't understand what you mean. I'm not doing any arc calculations in my question, just finding a point. If you're told that the reference is at 20 degrees, and you go 130 degrees, then you're finding the point that is 150 degrees clockwise from the positive x-axis. If that's the case, you just plug in 150 to my code

Comment: So you mean that in order to find the center point (not a coordinate) of an arc we have to sum the starting and ending degrees (20 and 130 in your example) and plug the result (150 degrees) as the `angle` parameter in your code?

Comment: @ColorWP.com I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. The center point of an arc is the same as the center point of the the circle of which the arc is a part. Oh! Maybe you're asking how to find the point midway between the end coordinates of the arc that is still along the arc. Well, if that's the case, then, find the average of the two end angles. For example, in your case, (20 deg + 130 deg)/2 = 75 deg. And then plug in 75 deg into the code to get the coordinates of the "center"/"midpoint" between the two ends of the arc. Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: You answered my answer precisely. My initial question was how to find the center point inside an arc (the area between 3 points: the circle center, starting arc point along the circle, ending arc point along the circle).