# drawBitmap over drawArc android

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

Hi I want to draw Bitmap over drawArc

till now I have done following things

I have done circular Progress using below code, I have done with first four at 45* degree

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher, options);
        srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        dstRect = new Rect(0,0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

onDrawMethod

```
  canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, innerCircleRadius, innerCirclePaint);
  canvas.drawArc(finishedOuterRect, getStartingDegree(), getProgressAngle(), false, finishedPaint);
  canvas.drawArc(unfinishedOuterRect, getStartingDegree() + getProgressAngle(), 360 - getProgressAngle(), false, unfinishedPaint);
  double radius = getWidth()/2;

    double x = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(-45);
    double y = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(-45);

    double x1 = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(-135);
    double y1 = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(-135);

    double x2 = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(-225);
    double y2 = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(-225);

    double x3 = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(-315);
    double y3 = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(-315);

    canvas.drawCircle(getStartingDegree(), getProgressAngle(), 100, innerCirclePaint);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (int)(x-bitmap.getWidth()/2), (int)(y-getWidth()/2), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (int)(x1-bitmap.getWidth()/2), (int)(y1-getWidth()/2), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (int)(x2-bitmap.getWidth()/2), (int)(y2-getWidth()/2), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (int)(x3-bitmap.getWidth()/2), (int)(y3-getWidth()/2), null);
```

screenshot is

[image]

Below is the images, which I want....

[image]

outline of above image is below

[image]

i want to draw bitmap over drawArc,

for that I have used reference from [Draw a Bitmap in Arc center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273040/draw-a-bitmap-in-arc-center) but it could not help me, I want to set co-ordinate (X,Y) in drawImage, please anybody who might can help me

I

Comment: so use `Canvas#drawBitmap`

Comment: @pskink thanks for your reply, please check my updated question, I know about drawbitmap but no knowledge of how to set where I want to set an Image

Comment: then read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations)